# Placing zeros as first number causes odd results

Tags: ruby

So I wanted to get my fundamental ruby skills up (coming from a python background) because I wanted to get a good handle on rails.

I was doing a bunch of exercises I picked for myself, and this particular error came up (it's not quite an error, but I'm raising an eyebrow) - for what it's worth, I'm using ruby 2.0.0.

```
    Class A
      def B(binaryNum)
        puts binaryNum
        binarray = binaryNum.to_s.chars.to_a
        indice = binarray.length
        puts "\n#{indice}"
      end
    end
conv = A.new()
puts "#{conv.B(1111)}"  # outputs 1111 as usual, with a length of 4
puts "#{conv.B(01111)}" # outputs 585, with a length of 3
```

It seems putting a zero in front of the integer representation of binary is causing all sorts of ruckus to occur. I initially thought it might be a silly error regarding maximum ints, but I reproduced the issue with much smaller numbers.

Comment: A couple of things: methods and variables `are_written_snake_case`, beginning with a lowercase letter; and I believe you mean `puts "\n#{indices}"`.

Comment: 111.to_s #=> "111" (base 10); 0111`.to_s #=> "73" (base 2). See [Fixnum#to_s](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-to_s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numeric literals with leading zeros in Ruby are treated as octal numbers.

According to the ruby-doc.org [documentation for numeric literals](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Numbers):

> You can use a special prefix to write numbers in decimal, hexadecimal,
>   octal or binary formats. For decimal numbers use a prefix of 0d, for
>   hexadecimal numbers use a prefix of 0x, **for octal numbers use a prefix
>   of 0 or 0o**, for binary numbers use a prefix of 0b. The alphabetic
>   component of the number is not case-sensitive.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> 0d170
> 0D170
>
> 0xaa
> 0xAa
> 0xAA
> 0Xaa
> 0XAa
> 0XaA
>
> 0252
> 0o252
> 0O252
>
> 0b10101010
> 0B10101010
> ```

So in your case, since 1111<sub>8</sub> = 585<sub>10</sub>, `01111.to_s` will return `"585"`.

---

Note that [`Fixnum#to_s`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s) takes an argument which lets you specifiy the base of the number system you are using. So for your program, you could do it like this:

```
class A
  def B(binaryNum)
    puts binaryNum
    binarray = binaryNum.to_s(2).chars.to_a
    indice = binarray.length
    puts "\n#{indice}"
  end
end

conv = A.new
puts "#{conv.B(0b1111)}" # Outputs 15, with a length of 4
puts "#{conv.B(01111)}"  # Outputs 585, with a length of 10
puts "#{conv.B(1111)}"   # Outputs 1111, with a length of 11
```

Even better, in Ruby 2.1+ `Fixnum` has an instance method called [`bit_length`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Fixnum.html#method-i-bit_length) which seems to already do what you want:

```
0b1.bit_length
#=> 1
0b11.bit_length
#=> 2
0b111.bit_length
#=> 3
0x1FF.bit_length
#=> 9
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby's numeric syntax is similar to C's, and the leading zero tells it to interpret the number as octal (base 8).

1111 base 8 = 585 base 10.